# MAT_DATE_LOCALE returns different output when compared to new Date().toLocaleDateString()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Trying to use MAT_DATE_LOCALE and provide the value as navigator.language so that the mat date picker shows the date format according to the users locale.
The issue i am facing is that for some languages it shows different output.

eg:- for English-IN the **MAT_DATE_LOCALE** gives **MM/DD/YYYY** format for date but if i try to do the same using `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-IN')` it returns **DD/MM/YYYY** (expected).